# Nagios NRPE won't allow arguments

Tags: linux, nagios, nrpe

I am trying to use a Nagios NRPE plugin to communicate with my servers. I have a command definition in `/etc/nagios/nrpe_local.cfg` to use it:

```
command[check_service]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_service -s $ARG1$
```

When I manually run the command in my terminal, it succeeds:

```
# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_service -s bind9
OK: Service bind9 is running!
```

When I try running it from my Nagios Server, it complains the command is not defined:

```
# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 10.32.10.3 -c check_service -a bind9
NRPE: Command 'check_service!bind9' not defined
```

Other `check_nrpe` commands work, so I don't think there is an issue in the server's `commands.cfg`, but here is the definition anyways:

```
define command {
    command_name        check_nrpe
    command_line        /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -t 30 -c $ARG1$
}
```

The check would look like this on the server:

```
define service {
    use                 local-service
    host_name           dc1,dc2
    service_description BIND Service
    check_command       check_nrpe!check_service!bind9
}
```

On the web interface, it returns **CRITICAL: Service is not running!**, which is not actually the case.

How can I get `check_nrpe` to allow the one extra argument? I have tried enabling `dont_blame_nrpe`, but that did not allow it to go either.

**Edit** - With debug turned on, and re-running the check, I get the following in my syslog:

```
Dec 19 09:01:56 dc1 nrpe[5586]: CONN_CHECK_PEER: checking if host is allowed: 10.32.10.12 port 33962
Dec 19 09:01:56 dc1 nrpe[5586]: Connection from 10.32.10.12 port 33962
Dec 19 09:01:56 dc1 nrpe[5586]: is_an_allowed_host (AF_INET): is host >10.32.10.12< an allowed host >10.32.10.12<
Dec 19 09:01:56 dc1 nrpe[5586]: is_an_allowed_host (AF_INET): is host >10.32.10.12< an allowed host >10.32.10.12<
Dec 19 09:01:56 dc1 nrpe[5586]: is_an_allowed_host (AF_INET): host is in allowed host list!
Dec 19 09:01:56 dc1 nrpe[5586]: Host address is in allowed_hosts
Dec 19 09:01:56 dc1 nrpe[5586]: Host 10.32.10.12 is asking for command 'check_service' to be run...
Dec 19 09:01:56 dc1 nrpe[5586]: Running command: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_service -s
Dec 19 09:01:56 dc1 nrpe[5587]: WARNING: my_system() seteuid(0): Operation not permitted
Dec 19 09:01:56 dc1 nrpe[5586]: Command completed with return code 2 and output: CRITICAL: Service  is not running!
Dec 19 09:01:56 dc1 nrpe[5586]: Return Code: 2, Output: CRITICAL: Service  is not running!
Dec 19 09:01:56 dc1 nrpe[5586]: Connection from 10.32.10.12 closed.
```

I have verified that the Group in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nagios-nrpe-server.service` matches the `nrpe_group` parameter in `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`. The same user exists in `/etc/group` and `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: `WARNING: my_system() seteuid(0): Operation not permitted` makes me think selinux?

Comment: @fukawi2 No SELinux setup on this VM (Debian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the Debian package does not set `--enable-command-args` when building the `nagios-nrpe-server` package, which is what's required to use `dont_blame_nrpe`.

Comment: :D - well glad I helped you get there!

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you restarted the nrpe daemon after enabling `dont_blame_nrpe`
2. Change the `debug` directive in nrpe.cfg to 1 and restart the daemon. You should get useful debug information in the logs after that.

Comment: Updated with the debug information. `dont_blame_nrpe` was turned on and the daemon started already. Thanks